# PHP OOP area of visibility

Tags: php

I got in trouble with area of area of visibility of my database object.

I have 3 classes (DbConnect, Db, Client)
DbConnect.php:

```
class DbConnect
{
  public static function getConnection($params)
  {
    try
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $params['host'] .';dbname='.$params['dbname'], $params['user'], $params['password']);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        exit('<div class="alert alert-red full-width">Unable connect to database: <b>'.$db_database.'</b></div>');
    }

    $pdo->exec("set names utf8");

    return $pdo;
  }
}
```

Db.php:

```
class Db
{
  function __construct($pdo)
  {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
  }

  function query($query)
  {
    $result = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result->execute();
    return $result->fetch();
  }
}
```

Client.php:

```
class Client
{
  function getClient()
  {
    $result = $DbClient->query('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE secret_key = \''.SECRET_KEY.'\'');

    return $result;
  }
}
```

Im trying to get client datas by following way:

```
$db_client = DbConnect::getConnection(include(ROOT.'u/'.$company.'/db_params.php')); //success
$DbClient = new Db($db_client); //success

$GetSecretKey = $DbClient->query("SELECT * FROM General"); // success
define('SECRET_KEY', $GetSecretKey['secret_key']);

echo SECRET_KEY; // displays the secret key, everything is ok

/*
* Get Client datas
*/
$client = new Client();
$result = $client->getClient(); // and at this moment it throw me an error
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: DbClient in /bla/bla/Client.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /bla/bla/Client.php on line 6

Help me someone to impove this part of my code please.
Thanks.

Comment: Your error suggests that `$DbClient` is null, but I am not sure how that could be with the code you provided.  Did you modify the code for this post?

Comment: `$DbClient` is a global variable, you have to define it inside your `getClient()` function with `global` keyword first before using it, please read [Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice: Undefined variable: DbClient in /bla/bla/Client.php on line 6
>
> $result = **$DbClient**->query...

Happening because you're trying to use `$DbClient` as an instance variable but you haven't defined it anywhere.

You can make a small change and inject an instance of `Db` into `Client` and then you'll have access to it. Define a constructor and pass in the Db instance. Set it to a class property that you can then access when needed.

**Client.php**

```
<?php
class Client
{
    protected $_db = null;

    public function __construct(Db $db)
    {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    function getClient()
    {
        $result = $this->_db->query('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE secret_key = \'' . SECRET_KEY . '\'');

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now, since you've defined a constructor that accepts an argument, you need to provide it when creating your client object.

**index.php**

```
$connection = DbConnect::getConnection([...]); 

// Notice that I changed the variable name to `$db`. This is a bit clearer than `$db_client`.
$db = new Db($connection); 

$GetSecretKey = $db->query("SELECT * FROM General");
define('SECRET_KEY', $GetSecretKey['secret_key']);

echo SECRET_KEY;

// Changed this variable name too, to be less confusing. 
// Pass in your $db instance, and you should be good to go. 
$client = new Client($db);
$result = $client->getClient();
```